# In SpineJS, what is the purpose of @extend when we already have 'extends'

Tags: spine.js

what's the difference between the coffeescript  'extends' and '@extend'? Extend is for inheritance but then is @extend for a mixin, but you only get one object you can mix in?

Comment: Because extends is not available in javascript. Same thing for Backbone. If a framework is meant for coffeescript only then it should be thrown in a garbage ...

Comment: Spoke to a colleague, seems that @extend is not for inheritance, it's about a mixin – enabling the addition of members from another object without inheritance. Furhtermore, coffeescript's 'extends' is simply a nicer looking semantic for what does actually exist in javascript – prototypal inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

@extend is not for inheritance, it's about a mixin – enabling the addition of members from another object without inheritance